# Swing HiDPI Border rendering (Windows 10/OpenJRE 11)

Tags: java, swing, border, graphics2d, hidpi

I maintain an old Swing application that uses custom [border](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/border/Border.html) implementations as window decorations with a `look and feel` implementation which extends [MetalLookAndFeel](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/plaf/metal/MetalLookAndFeel.html). The `look and feel` overrides `initComponentDefaults(UIDefaults table)` and installs the custom border as `"RootPane.frameBorder"` and so on.

The custom border itself draws 32 lines of predefined colors horizontally together by implementing `paintBorder(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height)`. This works fine with Windows 10 2004 or newer when the `display scaling` is set to 100% in `Settings > Display > Scale and layout`. When `display scaling` is set to 125% or more, the border will not be drawn correctly, it has white lines between the lines that should be drawn together.

`Fix scaling for apps` in `Advanced scaling settings` seems to not affect the border drawing.

I use `AdoptOpenJDK OpenJDK 11.0.4+11 x64`. I expect Swing to scale the lines up too, like fonts, etc.

Why this is happening? How this might be fixed?

The border implementation:

```
public class CustomWindowBorder implements Border{

   public static final int BORDER_THICKNESS = 3;
   
   private static final CustomWindowBorder globalInstance = new CustomWindowBorder();

   public static CustomWindowBorder getInstance(){

      return CustomWindowBorder.globalInstance;
   }

   private CustomWindowBorder(){}
   
   @Override
   public Insets getBorderInsets(Component c){

      return new Insets(1,
                        CustomWindowBorder.BORDER_THICKNESS,
                        CustomWindowBorder.BORDER_THICKNESS,
                        CustomWindowBorder.BORDER_THICKNESS);
   }

   @Override
   public boolean isBorderOpaque(){

      return true;
   }

   @Override
   public void paintBorder(Component c,
                           Graphics g,
                           int x,
                           int y,
                           int width,
                           int height){

      Color[] decorationColors = [ommited]; // 30 colors in total
      Color[] borderColors = [ommited]; // 3 colors in total

      int yStart = 30;

      for(int i = 0; i < decorationColors.length; i++ ){
         // top
         Color clr = decorationColors[i];
         g.setColor(clr);

         g.drawLine(0,
                    i,
                    width,
                    i);
      }

      for(int i = 0; i < borderColors.length; i++ ){
         Color clr = borderColors[i];
         g.setColor(clr);

         // left
         g.drawLine(i,
                    yStart,
                    i,
                    height - i - 1);
         // right
         g.drawLine(width - i - 1,
                    yStart,
                    width - i - 1,
                    height - i - 1);
         // below
         g.drawLine(i,
                    height - i - 1,
                    width - i - 1,
                    height - i - 1);
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that Swing draws exactly one un-scaled pixel wide lines on the screen when using `Graphics::drawLine` or `Graphics::fillRect` with one pixel width or height, independently from Windows's display scaling.

When I draw the border with `Graphics::fillRect` and let it fill every 30 horizontal lines of the top and 3 lines on the other sides, the white space will be filled completely.

My solution is to draw each line over `Graphics::fillRect` and fill the whole remaining lines with the color, reducing the width/height of the filled rectangle while moving it to the next line. It's not the most efficient way to draw this, but it works for me.

The modified paintBorder method:

```
@Override
public void paintBorder(Component c,
                        Graphics g,
                        int x,
                        int y,
                        int width,
                        int height){

   Color[] decorationColors = [ommited]; // 30 colors in total
   Color[] borderColors = [ommited]; // 3 colors in total

   int yStart = 30;

   for(int i = 0; i < decorationColors.length; i++ ){
      // top
      Color clr = decorationColors[i];
      g.setColor(clr);

      g.fillRect(0,
                 i,
                 width,
                 decorationColors.length - i);
   }

   for(int i = 0; i < borderColors.length; i++ ){
      Color clr = borderColors ;
      g.setColor(clr);

      // left
      g.fillRect(i,
                 yStart,
                 borderColors.length - i,
                 height - yStart - i);

   }
   for(int i = borderColors.length - 1; i >= 0; i-- ){
      Color clr = borderColors[i];
      g.setColor(clr);

      // right
      g.fillRect(width - i - 1,
                 yStart,
                 borderColors.length - i,
                 height - yStart - i);
      // below
      g.fillRect(i,
                 height - i - 1,
                 width - i,
                 borderColors.length - i);
   }
}
```